# From Blender to Unity, model looks horrible

Tags: mesh, uv

im trying to figure out since 2 days why my exported model look horrible ..

there is a picture how it look like in Blender and another in Unity, can someone tell me what i might did wrong?

Im Kinda new to Blender so any help is apreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably some render settings in the projects, or import settings gone wrong. Anyway that's a question about Unity usage really, nothing to do in Blender stackexchange.

Comment: aight, at least someone who could give me a hint on where to search for the problem, thank you

Comment: Probably a Unity problem, not Blender. Ask around on the Unity forums, I guess.

Comment: im trying to make now a Light/Occ/Normal etc Map and try to play around with this, if this doesnt work, i will have to keep searchin i gues, thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Unity

Comment: Besides your strange material setup in Blender, the problem seems to be on the Unity side.

Comment: I don't think vector displacement works in unity... Maybe try using normal map

Answer (score 0):

so Answer of the Problem were not "unity" neither "blender", it was me x) ,

if i want a super good texture in Unity or anywhere else, i always need a Normal, Occ, Light map ..

here is the reference:

[image]